# simple walk on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: probability, random-walk

Consider the simple random walk $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ starting from $X_0 = 0$.

Consider $\varepsilon>0$, show that, for all $\delta>0$,
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\left|X_{n}\right|}{n^{\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon}}>\delta\right)=0 .
$$

I'm new to random walks in probability and don't know how to solve this.

Comment: What does the Central Limit Theorem imply?

Comment: It implies that $n^{1/2} \frac{S_n - \mathbb{E}[X_1]}{\sqrt{Var(X_1)}}$ converges to a standard normal distribution.

Comment: So intuitively, the quantity you’re interested escapes into the tail of the normal distribution. Make this argument rigorous by using the fact that $X_n/\sqrt(n)$ converges to a standard normal.

Comment: What do you mean with "the quantity you're interested escapes into the tail of the normal distribution"?

Comment: @vitalmath It's probably easier to see if you rewrite $(|X_n|/n^{1/2+\varepsilon}>\delta)$ as $(|X_n|/n^{1/2}>\delta n^{\varepsilon})$.